# Unable to set uid for ics by concatenating string variable

Tags: python, icalendar, meeting-request

When I concatentate the uid with a string variable the meeting invitation ics attachment does not get created properly, but when I hardcode an entire string

```
"UID: hardcoded string"
```

This creates the meeting invitation ics attachment correctly. I do not know how to get around this. I do not want to use getuniqueid() function, since I want to be able to cancel the meeting invitation request as well.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders
import os, datetime

def meeting_invitation(toAddr, body, datetimeStrP, method, uid):
    CRLF = "\r\n"
    attendees = toAddr
    organizer = "ORGANIZER;CN=organiser:mailto:do.not.reply"+CRLF+" @engr.orst.edu"
    fro = "<do.not.reply@me.com>"

    ddtstart = datetimeStrP
    dtoff = datetime.timedelta(hours = 8) # Correct -8 hour UTC offset correction
    dur = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15)
    ddtstart = ddtstart + dtoff
    dtend = ddtstart + dur
    dtstamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    dtstart = ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    dtend = dtend.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")

    if method == "REQUEST":
        status = "CONFIRMED"
    elif method == "CANCEL":
        status = "CANCELLED"

    description = "DESCRIPTION: Meeting invitation "+CRLF
    attendee = ""
    for att in attendees:
        attendee += "ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;" \
                    "ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;" \
                    "PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;" \
                    "RSVP=TRUE"+CRLF+" ;" \
                    "CN="+att+";" \
                    "X-NUM-GUESTS=0:"+CRLF+" " \
                    "mailto:"+att+CRLF
    ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR"+CRLF+\
           "PRODID:pyICSParser"+CRLF+\
           "VERSION:2.0"+CRLF+\
           "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN"+CRLF
    ical+="METHOD:"+method+CRLF+\
          "BEGIN:VEVENT"+CRLF+\
          "DTSTART:"+dtstart+CRLF+\
          "DTEND:"+dtend+CRLF+\
          "DTSTAMP:"+dtstamp+CRLF+organizer+CRLF
    ical+= "UID:"+uid+CRLF
    ical+= "UID:%s" %(uid)+CRLF
    # ical['uid']=uid+CRLF
    ical+= attendee+\
           "CREATED:"+dtstamp+CRLF+\
           description+\
           "LAST-MODIFIED:"+dtstamp+CRLF+\
           "LOCATION:"+CRLF+\
           "SEQUENCE:0"+CRLF+\
           "STATUS:"+status+CRLF
    ical+= "SUMMARY: Meeting invitation "+ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%d @ %H:%M")+CRLF+\
           "TRANSP:OPAQUE"+CRLF+\
           "END:VEVENT"+CRLF+\
           "END:VCALENDAR"+CRLF

    eml_body = body
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['Reply-To']=fro
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = "Advising Meeting "+ status #+ dtstart
    msg['From'] = fro
    msg['To'] = ",".join(attendees)

    part_email = MIMEText(eml_body, "plain")
    part_cal = MIMEText(ical,'calendar;method='+method)

    msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg.attach(msgAlternative)

    ical_atch = MIMEBase('application/ics',' ;name="%s"'%("invite.ics"))
    ical_atch.set_payload(ical)
    Encoders.encode_base64(ical_atch)
    ical_atch.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'%("invite.ics"))

    eml_atch = MIMEBase('text/plain','')
    Encoders.encode_base64(eml_atch)
    eml_atch.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "")

    msgAlternative.attach(part_email)
    msgAlternative.attach(part_cal)

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('mail.server', 587)
    mailServer.sendmail(fro, attendees, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
```

Comment: are you sure your uid variable is actually a string? to check you could use 
`if isinstance(uid, str):`

Comment: It is. Found out it was a Gmail issue when I was testing, but it works on Outlook, where it will actually be used to send meeting invitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered it was a Gmail issue when I was testing, but it works on Outlook, where it will actually be used to send meeting invitations.